# Right align new hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add a new hyper link using jquery/javascript right aligned to "View Results" in below script ?

[This is very long test question to test how polldaddy handles questions that exceed that normal length............ yes a very long question indeed..............](http://polldaddy.com/poll/6352993/)​

In below example there is a new hyper link with same name "View Results"

[image]

I think I need to modify class - 'pds-view-results'

http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/25LjE/14/

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.pds-view-results').after('<a href="#">test</a>')
```

**Initialization:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pds-view-results').after('<a href="#">test</a>')
});
```

**OR**

```
$(function(){
    $('.pds-view-results').after('<a href="#">test</a>')
});
```

**OR**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.pds-view-results').after('<a href="#">test</a>')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below piece of jquery should do it:

```
$(function() {
   $("span.pds-links a").addClass('pds-vote-button');
    $("span.pds-links").css("display","inline");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/21/)**